# umask not setting properly

Tags: permissions, login

I've been looking all over the internet for a way to set my system default umask in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Every suggestion, even from the pam_umask.so manpage, fails.

I can set the umask to 0002 instead of Ubuntu's 0022 in my .bashrc file, but this only affects shell commands. I want something that also affects the permissions of newly created directories with the desktop GUI, and other applications as well.

I've tried adding the line:
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0002
in the following /etc/pam.d/ files:
login
common-session
commion-session-noninteractive

To no avial.  I've set the UMASK in /etc/login.def to 002, and set USERGROUP_ENABLED to both yes and no.  No effect.
I've also added to the GECOS field of my account chfn -o umask=0002

None of these things has had any effect. The other suggestion in the manpage for pam_umask.so is to edit an /etc/default/login file, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: No.  I just manually change permissions for stuff after creating it.